# Error using fzero

Tags: matlab, function, minimum

I need to know the minimum of the curve `y= sin(r)+r.^2` using `fzero`.
I created a function:

```
function w=myfun(r)
w=diff(sin(r)+r.^2);
end
```

Then at the command window:

```
r=[-pi:.01:pi];
fzero( @myfun,0)
```

But there is always an error:

> Operands to the `||` and `&&` operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.
>
> Error in `fzero` (line 327)
>      `elseif ~isfinite(fx) || ~isreal(fx)`
>
> `fzero(@myfun,0)`

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

`diff` computed the finite difference derivative (i.e. the difference between neighbors). Here, `r` is scalar, so `diff` returns an empty array.

You will need to define your function `myfun` such that it returns the derivative given a single value. So you will have to manually compute the derivative function and write that into `myfun`.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Cris, you cannot use diff, as it finds the difference between neighbouring points (with one value, this difference is undefined.).

Instead, you can do one of the following

**Take the derivative yourself:**

```
function w=myfun(r)
w=cos(r)+2*r;
end
```

**Do a numerical differentiation**

```
function dw=myfun(r)
h = sqrt(eps);
wh=(sin(r+h)+(r+h).^2;
w= (sin(r)+(r).^2;
dw = (wh - w)/(h);
end
```

**Alternatively, use a numerical minimizer**

```
w= @(r) (sin(r)+(r).^2;
xmin = fminsearch(w,0);
```